# PHP | Get input name through $_POST[]

Tags: php, post, properties

HTML example:

```
  <form method="post" id="form" action="form_action.php">
    <input name="email" type="text" />
  </form>
```

User fills input field with: dfg@dfg.com

```
echo $_POST['email']; //output: dfg@dfg.com
```

The name and value of each input within the form is send to the server.
Is there a way to get the name property?
So something like..

```
echo $_POST['email'].name; //output: email
```

EDIT:
To clarify some confusion about my question;

The idea was to validate each input dynamically using a switch. I use a separate validation class to keep everything clean. This is a short example of my end result:

```
//Main php page
if (is_validForm()) {
    //All input is valid, do something..
}

//Separate validation class    
function is_validForm () {
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        if (!is_validInput($name, $value)) return false;
    }
    return true;
   }

function is_validInput($name, $value) {
    if (!$this->is_input($value)) return false; 

    switch($name) {
        case email: return $this->is_email($value);  
        break;
        case password: return $this->is_password($value);
        break;
//and all other inputs
        }
    }
```

Thanks to raina77ow and everyone else!

Comment: You know that the array key is actually the `name`, so when you know the key why would you need to do that? Perhaps you can suggest what you're trying to do.

Comment: See my comment below for clarification :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can process $_POST in `foreach` loop to get both names and their values, like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
   echo $name; // email, for example
   echo $value; // the same as echo $_POST['email'], in this case
}
```

But you're not able to fetch the name of property from `$_POST['email']` value - it's a simple string, and it does not store its "origin".

Comment: Careful about mass-assignment attacks, though.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Care to elaborate? I'm coming across that term for the first time

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
 echo 'Key is: '.$key;
 echo 'Value is: '.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it dynamically though, you could do it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo 'Name: ', $key, "\nValue: ", $value, "\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop your `object/array` with `foreach`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $items) {
    echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

Or you can use `var_dump` or `print_r` to debug large variables like `arrays` or `objects`:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
```

Or

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found something that might work for you, have a look at this-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

This page says that the code below,

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'fruit1' => 'apple',
    'fruit2' => 'orange',
    'fruit3' => 'grape',
    'fruit4' => 'apple',
    'fruit5' => 'apple');

// this cycle echoes all associative array
// key where value equals "apple"
while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
    if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}
?>
```

would give you the output,

fruit1
fruit4
fruit5

As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

current(array_keys($_POST))
should give you what you are looking for. Haven't tested though.

Answer (score 0):

Nice neat way to see the form names that are, or will be submitted

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
echo "</b><p>".$i." ".$name; 
echo " = <b>".$value; 
$i++;
}
?>
```

Just send your form to this script and it will show you what is being submitted.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a foreach Loop to get all values that are set.

```
foreach ($_POST AS $k=>$v){
    echo "$k is $v";
}
```

Your example

```
echo $_POST['email'].name; //output: email
```

wouldnt make sense, since you already know the name of the value you are accessing?

Comment: $k would be the key of the array and $v would be the value of that key

Comment: Please go, read and understand the difference between double quotes and single quotes before rating other posts down. thx.

Comment: Oh that I thought you were referring to `$k=>$v`

Comment: @dognose, See my comment for clarification. Thanks for help!